# Spring File Inbound Channel Adapter slows down

Tags: spring-integration

I have a spring-integration flow that starts with a file inbound-channel-adapter activated by a transactional poller (tx is handled by atomikos).
The text in the file is processed and the message goes down through the flow until it gets sent to one of the JMS queues (JMS outbound-channel-adapter).
In the middle, there are some database writes within a nested transaction.
The system is meant to run 24/7.

It happens that the single message flow, progressively slows down and when I investigated, I found that the stage that is responsable for the increasing delay is the read from filesystem.

Below, the first portion fo the integration flow:

```
<logging-channel-adapter id="logger" level="INFO"/>
<transaction-synchronization-factory id="sync-factory">
    <after-commit expression="payload.delete()" channel="after-commit"/>
</transaction-synchronization-factory>
<service-activator input-channel="after-commit" output-channel="nullChannel" ref="tx-after-commit-service"/>



<!-- typeb inbound from filesystem -->
<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="typeb-file-inbound-adapter"
                              auto-startup="${fs.typeb.enabled:true}"
                              channel="typeb-inbound"
                              directory="${fs.typeb.directory.in}"
                              filename-pattern="${fs.typeb.filter.filenamePattern:*}"
                              prevent-duplicates="${fs.typeb.preventDuplicates:false}" >
    <poller id="poller"
            fixed-delay="${fs.typeb.polling.millis:1000}"
            max-messages-per-poll="${fs.typeb.polling.numMessages:-1}">
        <transactional synchronization-factory="sync-factory"/>
    </poller>
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>
<channel id="typeb-inbound">
    <interceptors>
        <wire-tap channel="logger"/>
    </interceptors>
</channel>
```

I read something about issues related to the prevent-duplicates option that stores a list of seen files, but that is not the case because I turned it off.
I don't think that it may be related to the filter (filename-pattern) because the expression I use in my config (*.RCV) is easy to apply and the input folder does not contain a lot of files (less than 100) at the same time.

Still, there is something that gradually makes the read from filesystem slower and slower over time, from a few millis to over 3 seconds within a few days of up-time.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution.
The issue was related to the specific version of Spring I was using (4.3.4) that is affected by a bug I had not discovered yet.
The problem is something about DefaultConversionService and the use of converterCache (look at this for more details https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14929).
Upgrading to a more recent version has resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove, or move files after they have been processed; otherwise the whole directory has to be rescanned.

In newer versions, you can use a [WatchServiceDirectoryScanner](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/files.html#watch-service-directory-scanner) which is more efficient.

But it's still best practice to clean up old files.

Comment: Yes, I am already doing the delete (I had tought about it).
As you can see, I have a transaction synch for this, but it does not solve.

`<transaction-synchronization-factory id="sync-factory">
    <after-commit expression="payload.delete()" channel="after-commit"/>
</transaction-synchronization-factory>`

Comment: I was reluctant to use a WatchServiceDirectoryScanner because I was afraid that the file could be picked up (more easily) before completely written by the process that put it in the folder. I know that it can be prevented with methods mainly related to the writer and supported by the reader, but at the moments we don't have any of those methods.

Comment: Does that `payload.delete()` do the trick? Is file really deleted after transaction? Can you confirm that processed files are deleted and are not held somewhere in between? I mean be sure that you close file resource after use.

Comment: That's a good point. I am sure that files are deleted, and in the early life of the application, it happens very quickly. I assumed that `payload.delete()` did not need any other finalization of the files, but I am gonna investigate better on this topic.

Comment: Well, `File.delete()` can return `false`, if file can't be deleted, but no any exceptions though. That's why I suggest you to ensure that this really does its purpose for your application.